# Excel custom function: Control filter/sort behavior for mixed (string) output

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have a column with cells computing a value representing file volumes in bytes and a function outputting a string converting to appropriate units (96949643551 -> "90.291 GiB") which I then decided to wrap around that value:
`=Format_Filesize(B3-B3*Settings!$B$4/E3)`

- `B3-B3*Settings!$B$4/E3` calculates the difference between the original file size *B3* using the original bitrate *E3* and the projected file size using a new bitrate in *Settings!$B$4*, and might result in something like 53954174.66
- `Format_Filesize()` returns `51,45 MiB` for this example

This was quite pleasing until I realized I might want to sort that column along with the others (using the "Data -> Sort&Filter -> Filter" functionality.

**Is there a way to either**

- Supply a handler for sort evaluations? Maybe create a custom class that has different getter functions or an override method like `onSort`?
- <s>or to dynamically decide what a cell displays? Like:

  `123456;"Display Text"` sorting using the whole value but only displaying "Display Text"?</s>
  nvm, Excel's A-Z/Z-A sorting is not natural sort

#### My thoughts so far:

1. I can have a column for sorting (Calculated number) and a column for pretty display (`Format_Filesize()` of the numeric cell)
   That's easy to do but ugly; ideally I'd hide the numeric column, but then I couldn't easily sort with it anymore
2. <s>I can use `=[NumericResult] & "; " & Fortmat_Filesize([NumericResult])` to have the numeric value in front for sorting and the formatted string to read on the right.</s>
   No, I can't: the filter sort function would sort strictly alphabetically (2>100)
3. I can write my own sort function and insert a shape or control tied to a sorting macro and click on that instead of using the Filter Sort functionality for that column
4. instead of a custom function to output a formatted string value, I could use a custom number format like `[<1024]##0.00" B";[<1048576]##0.00," KB";##0.00,," MB"`
   Downsides:
   - I'd have to use base 10 units (KB, MB) instead of base 2 units (KiB, MiB)
   - Only a maximum of 2 conditions are possible, followed by a catch-all, which means that it would display 5.34 TB as 5340000 MB

I think 1 or 2 are pretty good work-arounds, but I'd be very interested in any better solutions, even if they're seemingly too complicated to be worth implementing - for fun and/or sake of completeness.

Comment: You could use a custom number format to display the formatted value and use the raw number for the cell value, but I think there's a limit to how many distinct formats you can use in a workbook (200-250?)

Comment: @TimWilliams how exactly do you mean? I've so far come across an SI units approximation (my work-around #4) using numeric thresholds to apply formats, but the conditions top out at 2(+1) max. Are you thinking about a separate format for each possible value, and is that why you're talking in the order of 100s of formats? :O

Comment: Yes - eg if the cell value is 96949643551 then the custom format is the formatted value "90.291 GiB"

Comment: @TimWilliams I see ^^ interesting idea, but I'm kind of glad its limit disqualifies it because that would be a nightmare of an approach that makes you feel awful for implementing it, yet I would feel compelled to try it ^^ __ But thank you, that's good input :)

Comment: #3 seems like the best alternative to needing an additional "unformatted size" column.  Your macro could switch the column to unformatted size, perform the sort, then switch back to formatted.

Comment: Oh, that would result in a long runtime in my case (I typically have thousands of values to parse) - I think re-calculating the values directly in the sort function would be noticeably faster. BUT I just realized that I could keep a hidden column and just use a tiny macro to still be able to sort with it, even though it's hidden. I think that's my new favorite now :)